# How do I get the part of a range that is not a union?

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can get the union of two ranges by writing:

```
Dim r1 as range
Dim r2 as range
Union(r1, r2)
```

But is there any I can get the range that is either in r1 or r2 but NOT in the union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub CombinedMinusIntersect()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngInt As Range, rngUnion As Range
    Dim rngFinal As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("A1:B5,C6:D10")
    Set rng2 = Range("D9:G16")

    Set rngUnion = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
    Set rngInt = Application.Intersect(rng1, rng2)

    If Not rngInt Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rngUnion
            If Application.Intersect(c, rngInt) Is Nothing Then
                If rngFinal Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngFinal = c
                Else
                    Set rngFinal = Application.Union(rngFinal, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Else
        Set rngFinal = rngUnion
    End If

    rngFinal.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Comment: That was the code I was going for that I found off-site.  Much cleaner.

Comment: Cool, very clever and a great utility function for me. I didn't know the answer would be this complex :-) Very easy to understand and clean code though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Union()` method ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) combines the ENTIRE ranges so there would never be parts of `r1` and `r2` that would not be in the `Union(r1, r2)`.

If however, you are looking for overlap (and cells that do not overlap) you could look into `Intersect()` method ([MSDN Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052685/how-do-i-get-the-part-of-a-range-that-is-not-a-union))
    Sub TestIt()

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:D4")
    Set r2 = Range("C3:F6")
    Set r3 = Intersect(r1, r2)
    r1.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    r2.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    r3.Cells.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    If r3 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Ranges do not overlap"
    Else
        MsgBox "r1 and r2 overlap at " & r3.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

A picture representation of `Intersect()` method:

[image]

[image]

There is some interesting functions related to finding the non-intersect portion.  I'd suggest @TimWilliam's answer [FOUND HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054992/4241535)

Comment: Can I get the range of the red and green area into one variable? I would like to set something like r = r.green + r.red

Comment: @user1283776 That gets more complicated, but I added a link and code from the site related to REMOVING a portion of the range.  So you'd want to remove the `Intersect` from the `Union`.

Answer (score 0):

If x belongs to r1 => x belongs to the union of r1 and somethings else.
There is nothing belonging to r1 that doesn't belong to the union.
And it the same for r2.